# Dropbox SDK for android: cannot find AndroidAuthSession

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to integrate dropbox in my android project following the tutorial on the dropbox website.
I referenced all the libraries that were in the sdk/libs path by "Add External JARs" into the preferences for my project.
But I get a

> AndroidAuthSession cannot be resolved to a type

for this declaration

```
private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;
```

error and don't know why.
These are my project imports done automatically with the cmd+shift+O command:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.Session.AccessType;
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: my libraries:
[image: Libraries]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little embarassed, but the problem was the wrong import of the dropbox-java libraries instead of the correct dropbox-android libraries!

Comment: I am so glad you decide to add your answer to your question. It helps other people like me when I search for the same problem you got.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top answer on Google, when searching for this issue, I will add what my problem with this was. :)

You have to download the SDK from the top of the Dropbox tutorial page. For example, the one I needed was here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android

Just click the link where it says Download Android SDK -- it's a special bundle containing the dropbox libraries. The full instructions are at the bottom of the page.

There are several other pages like this one, containing different useful Dropbox libraries.

Hope this would be of help to someone!

Answer (score 0):

"Since this is the top answer on Google" - no DB droid sdk in 2017. It's only java sdk and one - not enough - android example.
[Here.](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Core-API-v2-Android-authentication-flow/td-p/175160)

p.s. learning DB auth somehow become challenging, tired of their messed up docs